# Stop word analyzer with stopwords_path not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, match, analyzer

I'm on ES2.3  and I have a list of stop words file that are a mix of upper case lower case 
I'm trying to create an analyzer that ignore the case of the stop words

```
 "stopword_analyzer": {
      "type": "standard",
      "ignore_case": "true"
      "stopwords_path": "stopwords_english.txt"
    }
```

I've tried using a singel stop word in upper to check if there was an issue with the  stopwords_path argumant

```
    "stopword_analyzer6": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords": "[UPPERCASE]",
      "ignore_case": "true"
    }
```

but this failed as well

I've also tried to apply a lower case filter , but didn't work as well

```
    "stopword_analyzer5": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords_path": "stopwords_english.txt",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended doing that did the trick , using a stop word filter with a lower case filter on a custom analyzer

```
"analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_stop":{
          "type": "stop",
          "ignore_case": "true",
          "stopwords_path": "stopwords_english.txt"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "stopword_analyzer7": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "stopwords_path": "stopwords_english.txt",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_stop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```